# Qt5 tr() macro does not translate text

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am trying to track down a bug in someone else's code where some text (but not all), is not getting translated by the tr() macro in the program. The strings in question that do not get translated are all translated in bulk in a function like so:

```
SafeStr extractStringFromContainer(UniContainer* p_uni_container, const SafeStr& key)
{
    SafeStr retval;

    UniObjString* p_str = extractEntry<UniObjString>(p_uni_container, key, false);
    if(p_str)
    {
        retval = p_str->ref();
        
        QString localizeString(QObject::tr(qPrintable(retval.c_str())));
        retval = localizeString.toLatin1().constData();

        localizeString = (QObject::tr("some string to translate"));
        localizeString = (QObject::tr("another string to translate"));
        .
        .
        .
        .
    }

    return retval;
}
```

None of the strings being passed to the tr() macro in that section show up translated in the program. I've verified that these strings appear in the .ts file with all our translations, but I've noted that they appear under the context for a class that has nothing to do with this function.

The extractStringFromContainer() function is not part of a class, and is simply defined in a header file.  I tried adding these strings to the "QObject" context in the TS file, but that did nothing. I also tried adding a debug message to the main QMainWindow class constructor printing out the original string and the tr() string, and it properly translated it.

Can strings not be translated by tr() outside of a Q_OBJECT class? Or is there a special syntax to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tr(text)` *macro* is meant for literal text. It must not be used in any other context. Whereas `QObject::tr` is *not* a general-purpose translation function, in that it expects there to be an established context, and such context is provided by the enclosing class. Using `QObject::tr` outside of methods will lead exactly to the problem you observe: the context is out of your control and seemingly random.

If you wanted translatable strings in a non-QObject class, then you'd add `Q_DECLARE_TR_FUNCTIONS(context)` to the class declaration (as the very first thing, and I mean it). Such class then provides its own `tr` function, that Qt has implemented for you, and you must not use e.g. `QObject::tr` in its stead.

For stand-alone functions, you should either create a dummy static class (without any instances) to use as a handy translation context, with `Q_DECLARE_TR_FUNCTIONS`, or provide the context *explicitly* to `QCoreApplication::translate`. You'd be using `translate` *instead of* `tr` in this case!

You really should [read the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/i18n-source-translation.html) in this case, since it does a fairly good job of explaining what to do, and what not to do, and provides examples exactly for your scenario. The exact example you want is (cited literally):

```
void same_global_function(LoginWidget *logwid)
{
    QLabel *label = new QLabel(
                QCoreApplication::translate("LoginWidget", "Password:"), logwid);
}
```